# Missing Required Parameter in Yii2 Gridview Action Button

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to add my own action button in Yii2-Kartik Gridview.
This is my custom button:
[image]

#### This is my code in index.php

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{edit}',
    'buttons' => [
        'edit' => function ($url, $model) {
         return Html::a('<button type="button" class="btn btn-edit-npwp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i></button>', $url, [
             'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Edit'),
             'data-toggle' => "modal",
             'data-target' => "#myModal",
             'data-method' => 'post',
             ]);
         },
     ],
    'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
       if ($action === 'edit') {
           $url = Url::toRoute(['vatout-faktur-out/add-data', 'id' => $model->fakturId], ['data-method' => 'post',]);
           return $url;
       }
     }
],
```

#### and this is my action in controller.php

```
public function actionAddData($id) {
    $model = new VatoutFakturOut();
    return $this->render('addData', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I want to process the data from the row that I've clicked the button.
But, this return error

> Missing required parameters: id

### Why does this happen? And how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: you might want to change your data-method to get, as your action is looking for $id in $_GET.

Comment: @Gunnrryy I've tried, an add `$value = $_GET['id'];` but it give me error 'Undefined index: id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `urlCreator` you used `if` statement to check, if action is `edit`, and if it is, you add param `id` to your button url. Otherwise it doesnt have one, so there's two solutions:

Remove `if` statement from:

```
'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
     $url = Url::toRoute(['vatout-faktur-out/add-data', 'id' => $model->fakturId]);
     return $url;
 }
```

Or remove`$id` from your `actionAddData()` - because youre not using it at all:

```
public function actionAddData() {
    $model = new VatoutFakturOut();
    return $this->render('addData', [
                'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, there's a mistake. This code successfully access the action, but I can't get the Id of the data.

Comment: Well, if you want to access `$id`, you have to use first method - remove `if` statement in `urlCreator`.

Comment: I've remove the `if` and add the `$id` in the action, but it still give me the same error

Comment: Yap, Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

Comment: Did you removed `['data-method' => 'post']`? And show this created URL which giving 400

Comment: No, I didn't. Here `http://localhost/vatout_gm/web/vatout/vatout-faktur-out/add-data`

Comment: This is url after removing `data-method`?

Comment: No, that is the url before removing the `data-method`. The button didn't work if the I remove the `data-method`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150087/discussion-between-yupik-and-blackjack).